# Separate columns with regular expressions

Tags: r, regex, database, dataframe, tidyverse

I'm having troubles for finding the correct regular expression to separate a single column into two.

This is my example.

```
Col 1
8.3 algo y algo mas
```

I want this

```
Col 1    Col 2
8.3       algo y algo mas
```

I have been trying this code.

```
library(tidyverse)
    base <- base %>%
separate(col 1, into c("col 2", "col 3"), sep = "\\s")
```

Comment: So your whole premise hinges on column 1 being a non-whitespace value, and column 2 being the rest ?

Comment: You need the "into" to have as many names as the separated string. If you use "\\s" it will split it into 5 not 2.

Comment: Try `sep="\\s{3,}"` if you are sure that there will be 3 or more whitespaces between columns. Adjust the value as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For safety, I think it is best to substitute every space after a number with an easily identifiable character...

`df[, 'Col 1'] <- gsub(pattern = '^([0-9\\.]+) ', replacement = '\\1_', x = df[, 'Col 1'])`

Then I would use `separate`:

`df <- separate(data = df, col = 'Col 1', into = c('Col 1', 'Col 2'), sep = '_')`

I would also change the column names, because spaces generally are a problem when in the column names... try changing to something like `col_1`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, theres a problem, when I run your code, the colums separate the first number before the point. May be I'm running wrong your code. I'm very new in this R enviroment.

Comment: Yeah, I should have paid attention that the point as a separator character would not be very nice since you already had points in the original data. I changed the separator, please let me know if this works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the functions from `stringr` and `rebus`:

```
df <- data.frame(Col_1 = "8.3 algo y algo mas")

library(stringr)
library(rebus)
str_match(df$Col_1, pattern = capture(DGT %R% DOT %R% DGT) %R%
                              SPC %R%
                              capture(one_or_more(or(SPC, LOWER))))
```

The `rebus` package allows you to build regular expressions piece by piece using human readable code. The output is as follows:

```
#      [,1]                  [,2]  [,3]             
# [1,] "8.3 algo y algo mas" "8.3" "algo y algo mas"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful